# Elliptic curve example

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve

I would like to use ECC to sign messages. I trying searching in google, but I was not able to find a commented code to understand how it works.

Do you know some documentation that explains not only the mathematical basis, but also how to implement it?

Comment: If you want to actually use ECC, you really should use an existing implementation. Writing a high performance implementation and avoiding side channel attacks is pretty tricky. A straight forward implementation using `BigInteger` libraries is typically hundreds or thousands of times slower than an optimized implementation. Side channel attacks are pretty annoying as well, for example with older versions of OpenSSL they could be used to steal ECC private keys.

Answer (score 4):

See [Johannes Bauer's ECC Tutorial](http://www.johannes-bauer.com/compsci/ecc/), based on Python and Sage. A small Python ECC library was published by [bellbind](https://gist.github.com/1414867).